# Can A Data Field in JSON format be parsed?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Java class as

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LogMessage {
   private String timestamp;
   private String level;
   private String message;
   private String loggername;
   private String thread;
}
```

The following code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
....
objectMapper.readValue(m, LogMessage.class);
```

will throw an expectation when a message field contains a JSON format data.

What will be a good way to deal with the problem?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had a luck with all approaches stated there with an exception on  serializing and  deserializing.